# Filter in Hibernate Join

Tags: hibernate

How could I add filters to a Join on Hibernate? I have an entity parent with three children, and I would like to filter data by some fields of these children entities. The JOIN it's created on my DAO through

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Cartel.class).add( create(instance) ).list();
```

I supposed that if I set the fields I want to filter by, Hibernate automatically would build the JOIN filtered by these fields but it returns all results (the select statement built only have 1=1 in the where clause).

Comment: If you would be kind enough to post more information about your Cartel class and other classes you want to use, and give an example of a select (with filter) you want to obtain, we could provide more useful information for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("xxx",Object);
```

Thanks.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, HQL doesn't allow the concept of an `ON` clause for joins, which is what you're alluding to.

You can however write raw SQL and use `createSQLQuery()` to execute arbitrary SQL, which can of course specify an `ON` clause (assuming your database supports it)

Comment: But the statement is correctly formed having JOIN with each child entity. The problem it is I'm not able to add filters to where clause of data set on these child entities.

Comment: Just use HQl then: `where parent.child.name = 'fred'` etc

Comment: I don't have any HQL, the JOIN it's built automatically with hbm and criteria.